# Set oracle user password expiry/grace period

Tags: oracle

I have an application storing it's data in an Oracle 11g Express Edition database. When the Oracle user password is starting to expire (entering grace period), the application is throwing an exception (ORA-28002) and just stops working. I need to find a way to keep the application running during that period and inform an administrator, so the password can be changed before it expires.

However my real problem is, I need to set my database user in that grace period so I can program and test my application and see if my code works. I tried to change the expiry date in dba_users, but I do not have the required privileges to do so. I'm not even sure this is the correct approach.

What could I do to make the database server think my user account will expire soon so I can write code to handle that event?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need privileges to do so at the database level. A normal user cannot even explicitly lock or expire his own account. (You can lock it by purposely using the wrong password if your profile is setup so)

The only other way I know to expire your user (without a database level command) is to fool the database by setting the clock forward.

If you don't have DBA privs, it is unlikely that you have privs to change the system clock.

> I tried to change the expiry date in dba_users, but I do not have the
>   required privileges to do so. I'm not even sure this is the correct
>   approach.

No, don't make changes to DBA_USERS. You would need to alter the PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME for the DEFAULT profile using "ALTER PROFILE" command. All associated changes require ALTER PROFILE system priv to do so. So, without DBA privs, you can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Look in USER_USERS

It will give you the logged in user's own expiry date so that your application can warn the user ahead of the account expiring.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Somehow my database admin changed the user profile from DEFAULT to EXPIREPROFILE. Then I modified the password life time and grace period of the profile:

```
ALTER PROFILE EXPIREPROFILE LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 1;
ALTER PROFILE EXPIREPROFILE LIMIT PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME 21;
```

I expired the account and changed the password. When I looked into dba_users the password expiry date was tomorrow. But after that the account didn't expire right away, it entered the 21 days grace period.

Now I can write code to handle this specific situation and test it. Thanks everyone for your help :)