# Change Oracle User Password Expiry Date

Tags: database, oracle

I have got oracle User Password Expiry date using,

`Select Expiry_date from USER_USERS;`

I want to throw a warning message when Password is about to expire.

Currently my password is not expiring soon. I want to change the Expiry date to prior date, So that I can test my code.

My user account password should be about to Expire. i.e. I want to get `ORA-28002` ERROR.

I tried using 
`alter user XYZ password expire;`

This sets my user `ACCOUNT_STATUS` to `EXPIRED` state but I want it to be in `EXPIRED(GRACE)` status.

Please suggest any possible method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set oracle user password expiry/grace period](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692437/set-oracle-user-password-expiry-grace-period)

Comment: Change the profile attached to this user. You can set `PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME` to a short value (even down to seconds).

Comment: I have done that but It doesn't go in `EXPIRED(GRACE)` state @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Did you login as this user? Otherwise the state is not updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a new user profile (or alter an existing one) like this:

```
CREATE PROFILE SHORT_LIFE_PROFILE LIMIT
    PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 1/24/60/60 --> = 1 second
    PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME 1/24; --> = 1 hour

ALTER USER rdj7 PROFILE SHORT_LIFE_PROFILE;
```

In order to get `ACCOUNT_STATUS = EXPIRED(GRACE)` you have to logon with this user, otherwise the status does not change.

```
C:\>sqlplus rdj7/*****@yourDB

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Mar 10 10:09:29 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-28002: the password will expire within 0 days

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning option

SQL>
```

Then you should see it:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_STATUS 
FROM DBA_USERS 
WHERE USERNAME = 'RDJ7';

ACCOUNT_STATUS                  
--------------------------------
EXPIRED(GRACE)     

1 row selected.
```

Comment: Typical Oracle, lets do it the convoluted way. Is there any reasoning behind why Oracle does it like this?