# create oracle user with an expiration date

Tags: oracle

I need to create an oracle user for only one week. From questions in SO, I know I can create it, and make his password expire. Like they say here

[Change Oracle User Password Expiry Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644192/change-oracle-user-password-expiry-date)

But when the user tries to access, he can change the password and can login again.

For instance with the password, I can make it expire creating a user and then a profile like this:

```
create user myuser identified by mypasswordr; 
create role mynormaluser;
grant create session to mynormaluser;
grant mynormaluser to myuser;



CREATE PROFILE minuevoperfil LIMIT
    PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 1/24/60/60
    PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME 1/24/60;

ALTER USER myuser PROFILE minuevoperfil;
```

Is there something like "USER_LIFE_TIME". that allows me to make the user unable to log in after some period of time?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to specify that. You could create a trigger on the LOGON event, and check if it is the user in question (or put in a table along with login date) and then if out of date range, raise an error.  Problem with that is the trigger will fire for EVERY login, which could affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with DBMS_jobs, perhaps this is not the good way to go, but maybe they could be used ?

```
begin
  sys.dbms_job.submit(job => :job,
                      what => 'SQL TO DELETE USER HERE',
                      next_date => to_date('27-05-2017 01:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                      interval => null);
  commit;
end;
```